# I've an exception when run android application (java.io.FileNotFoundException)?

Tags: android

whats this file ?!!! i don't delete it !!
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png

```
12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #101: Error inflating class <unknown>
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at ayanoo.forms.UserView.<init>(UserView.java:50)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at ayanoo.forms.SearchResultForm.addUser(SearchResultForm.java:124)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at ayanoo.forms.SearchResultForm.doSearch(SearchResultForm.java:105)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at ayanoo.forms.SearchResultForm$1.onClick(SearchResultForm.java:55)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:65)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 22 more
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f060057
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:327)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:69)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 26 more
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-mdpi/scrollbar_handle_vertical.9.png
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:405)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
    12-06 14:26:33.606: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(276):     ... 30 more
    12-06 14:26:56.035: ERROR/MetadataRetrieverClient(33): failed to extract an album art
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem, but closing the IDE and cleaning the project didn't help for me. it seems to be related to the ImageView i have in my layout file. if i remove the ImageView, the exception goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes Eclipse stucks with this .. just close IDE and start it again.
and try to rebuild project.

Comment: Adham, its 'double check' not 'double click'

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build the project, then double-check the path to the resource.